# add class visible to grid-item but not those items that has class new

Tags: jquery

I tried to add a class visible to `.grid-items` but not those `hasClass('new')`.
I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to be working.
What is wrong here please?

html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item new">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item new">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item new">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item new">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item psd">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item psd">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item wordpress">//some code here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 grid-item joomla">//some code here</div>
```

js code:

```
var visibleTrue = $('.grid-item').hasClass('new');
if(visibleTrue){
  $('.grid-item').removeClass('visible');
}
else{
  $('.grid-item').addClass('visible');
}
```

Comment: Please write html  also. code looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanna do.
Anyway, I suppose you have many .grid-item elements in your DOM, var visibleTrue become true when find one .grid-item with class "new". 
At this point, visibleTrue still true and your code doesn't work for other divs.

I think you wanna cycle all the elements to check if they have the new class and in case add or remove "visible" class.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".grid-item" ).each(function() {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('new')){
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      }
    });
});
```

Here you can find .each reference https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to add visible class to every .grid-itme but except .grid-items that has class new. that's what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add class visible where class `.grid-item` is there but not `.new`:

```
$(".grid-item").not('.new').addClass('visible');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uos6epz/2/)

Comment: I've tried this but not working. I've edited the code. can you please have a look again?

Comment: Can you check the updated fiddle link with your data ? its working fine with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.grid-item').each(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('new')){
        $(this).addClass('visible');
   }

});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/aw1rdz5v/7/)